# How does cin work?

Tags: c++, iostream

I ran this code

```
char c;
cin >> c;
cout << c;
cin >> c;
cout << c;
```

and wrote to the console `ab`, the pressed enter. So I got `ab` at the next line. But I can't understand how it works. Before pressing enter the program doesn't read anything, right? After pressing, it reads `a`, save it to `char c`, then reads `char c`, writes `a` to the console. It's OK. But how can it read `b` being at the second line? It isn't `b` at the second line

Comment: `'c'` is a `char` type and you perform `cin >> c;` twice, which means it'll read two `char`s when they're available. So, it reads `'a'` then prints it via `cout << c;` and then reads `'b'` and prints it. Therefore, it is expected that `'a'` and `'b'` are printed (e.g., `ab`).

Comment: @JamesAdkison but when the program wrote `b`, it is located at the second line. How can it return back to the first line?

Comment: Not quite sure how cin works internally, but it does expect a new line (Enter) press for when you finish your input. So, what it reads is probably "a\n" but it only shows you the a in the first cout. Then, same goes for "b\n" but again shows you b. Cin eats up that '\n', the new line character. Good reads: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore. The second one particularly has an example on how to ignore N characters or up to the, well, expected '\n' character. EDIT: For your comment here, you pressed the enter so it moved down :)

Comment: @Pavel If you still have questions, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if you could show exactly what you're input looks like and the output you're seeing (i.e., [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36914079/edit) your question to add these details).

Comment: @JamesAdkison I would say the concept is quite clear from the code currently in the question. Why force the user to add a `main` and `using namespace std;` (or what do you feel is missing from an MCVE)? They're unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Angew Yes, the code is pretty clear but exactly what their input is and the output would be better to be explicitly shown. It sounds to me like the input is `ab` (on one line) then output is `ab` (on second line) but based on OP's comments it sounds like they are confused or I didn't understand the input and output. It's very often that people post code that **doesn't reflect they code they are actually using**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cin is a blocked input. Whatever comes from the keyboard is stored in a buffer. When you press enter the system passes the buffer to the application code (std::cin code). Operator >> will decide how much to read from that buffer - one char, string, int, float etc. Depends on the type of the operand.

Answer (score 20):

`cin` is the standard input **stream**. The streaming nature is vital in-depth for understanding C++ I/O.

By default, doing `cin >> x` means:

> From the point currently in the stream, skip any whitespace which might be there and then keep reading as long as possible & necessary to get a valid representation of `x`.

Let us disregard for a moment the fact that input comes from the keyboard. The content of the stream at start is `a b LINEFEED`. You execute `cin >> c`, which will read the first character, `a`, from input. That's enough to fill in `c`, so reading stops. The `cin` stream now contains `b LINEFEED`. The variable `c` is then written to standard output.

Another `cin >> c` comes next, so one more character is read (this time `b`). Again, one character is enough, so reading ends and the stream contents is just `LINEFEED`. The `b` is then sent to the standard output stream.

The fact that the standard input and standard output streams are normally tied to the console does not affect their internal working in any way. `cin` doesn't "forget" what was in it just because some output appeared on the screen in the meantime. In particular, `cin` reads the *keyboard,* not "characters on the console." It just so happens that pressing keys both echoes them on the console and feeds them to `cin`.

So the fact that your program has output the character `a` in the meantime has no effect on the contents of the `cin` stream.

Answer (score 2):

cin and cout are buffered streams. Both 'a' and 'b' goes into the input buffer when you press enter. The '>>' operator reads from that buffer (one char at a time in your case). The '<<' writes to the output buffer. The only thing that should surprise you is that you see "ab" on output without printing "\n" (the latter symbol should flush the contents of the output buffer to the terminal).

In short, both cin and cout are buffers. Input and output operators work with those buffers. Newline symbol initiates the data transfer from real input to input buffer and from output buffer to the real output.

There more thing about I/O you can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `cin` has an overload for data type `char` to only grab 1 character from the input stream, so your program basically goes like this :

```
char c;
cin >> c; // reads 'a' from the input stream (input stream contains 'ab\n')
cout << c; // prints 'a'
cin >> c; // changes c to 'b' (reads 'b')
cout << c; // prints 'b'
```